# Apache2 vhost redirects https ubuntu 17.04

Tags: apache2, virtualhost, https

I run Virtualbox with ubuntu server 17.04 and it does this redirect to SSL/https when I try to access the local project in the browser

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin admin@example.host
DocumentRoot "/media/sf_www/dashboard/public"
DirectoryIndex index.php
ServerName dashboard.dev
ServerAlias dashboard.dev www.dashboard.dev
<Directory "/media/sf_www/dashboard/public">
    Options All
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/dashboard_error.log
# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel warn 
#rewrite:trace6
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/dashboard_access.log combined
```

I know this question has been asked multiple times but nothing I try is working for me sadly

Comment: And what's in your default apache aite config?

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen I user the default config in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf but added `IncludeOptional /media/sf_www/vhosts/dashboard.conf` to access vhost files with a shared folder